# Why does this DAX relationship between tables not aggregate as expected?

Tags: dax, powerpivot

A very basic question about relationships between tables:

I have made a test with two tables ("Dates" and "Facts") and have connected them via an ID field:

[image]

When I try to count and group the count by Dates[YearMonth], I am only getting the expected results for the Facts[BirthID] column, and not for the Facts[StartID] or Facts[EndID]. So I am only getting the expected results from the column that is the  relationship to the Dates table (where the YearMonth column is that I am trying to group by. [This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6fFg.png) shows the tables, expected results and actual results:
[image]

This is probably very simple, but I can't figure out why it is not aggregating the data "correctly" by YearMonth.

Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The joining is happening on BirthID. Don't understand what else would you expect.

Answer (score 0):

We get same count for Facts[StartID] or Facts[EndID] because the join is on BirthID. If we change the join to use Facts[StartID] or Facts[EndID] we get the expected results as you have shown.

We can also create inactive relationship and activate the relationship with DAX USERELATIONSHIP function. Then we get the expected results.

[USERELATIONSHIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/userelationship-function-dax)